# Revalidar o resetear un campo con jquery validation

Tags: jquery-validate

Tengo una serie de Checkbox, que cuando seleccionas uno en específico despliega otros campos, pero los campos también e de validarlos, el caso es que si decido quitar la selección quiero que revalide, puesto que ya no debería requerir ciertos campos, ejemplo.

[image: Este es el ejemplo real]

Básicamente sólo tengo esto

```
$('#mdlChckSancion8').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked') == true) {
        $("#rowInhabilitado").show(500);
    } else {
        $("#txtFechaInicio").val('');
        $("#txtFechaFin").val('');
        $("#rowInhabilitado").hide(500);
    }
});
```

Este es el código con el que valido

```
$("#frmPartSanc").validate({
        rules: {            
            txtFechaInicio: {
                required: true,
            },
            txtFechaFin: {
                required: true,
            },
            mdlTxtPlazo: {
                required: true,
            },
        },
        submitHandler: function() {
            Guardar();
        },
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-danger');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-danger').addClass('has-success');
        },
        errorClass: 'text-danger',
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            } else if (element.prop('type') === 'checkbox') {
                error.appendTo(element.parent().parent().parent());
            } else if (element.prop('type') === 'radio') {
                error.appendTo(element.parent().parent().parent());
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        },
    });
```

Antes validaba con form Validation pero no tenía este problema, quisiera saber si con jquery validation, ya que lo tengo un poco avanzado en cuanto a validaciones

Comment: Coloca más código, incluyendo la tu script de jquery validation

Comment: No me permite poner en comentarios tanto código, pero es el ejemplo básico de la función validate
https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Comment: Puedes editar la publicación.. pero tengo una idea, prueba a ver si te sirve, primero mete esa validación dentro de un div con un id, y cuando quieras volver a validar, reescribe el div con tu nuevo JS sin problemas, así puedes reescribir toda tu función cada que valides

Comment: Suena viable, aunque se me hace lata destruir y construir XD acabo de agregar el código con el que valido